# ggplot2 Graph colors do not match with what I coded

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

The display of the graph colors does not match with what I coded. It only displays the first color correctly. When it comes to the second color, it just displays grey, regardless of what color code I input.

The data is this:

```
A tibble: 2 × 4
  work_from_home     n  prop  ypos
  <lgl>          <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 NA             13437  55.0  27.5
2 TRUE           11009  45.0  77.5
```

I made a pie chart in this way:

```
count_work_from_home$prop<-as.integer(count_work_from_home$prop)

mycols <-c("#EFC000FF", "#CD534CFF")
plotting_work_from_home<-ggplot(count_work_from_home, aes(x="", y=prop, fill=work_from_home))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white")+
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  geom_text(aes(y=ypos, label=prop), color ="white")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=mycols)+
  theme_void()+
  labs(title="Remote jobs vs.Non-remote jobs")
```

The result is this:
[image]

I tried to change "NA" into some other values to see the gray color is because of "NA".
I did like this:

```
count_work_from_home <- count_work_from_home %>%
  mutate(work_from_home=as.character(work_from_home)) %>%
  mutate(work_from_home=replace_na(work_from_home,"Unknown"))
```

As a result, the tibble now looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  work_from_home     n  prop  ypos
  <chr>          <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Unknown        13437  55.0  27.5
2 TRUE           11009  45.0  77.5
```

[image]

This result is what I wanted. So it is good. HOWEVER, when I tried to change "TRUE" to "Yes" - and thus the tibble looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  work_from_home     n  prop  ypos
  <chr>          <int> <int> <dbl>
1 Unknown        13437    54  27.5
2 Yes            11009    45  77.5
```

And I made a pie chart with the same code-

```
plotting_work_from_home<-ggplot(count_work_from_home, aes(x="", y=prop, fill=work_from_home))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white")+
    coord_polar("y", start=0)+
    geom_text(aes(y=ypos, label=prop), color ="white")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=mycols)+
    theme_void()+
    labs(title="Remote jobs vs.Non-remote jobs")
```

The result was like this:
[image]

**I do not understand why the label 45 and 54 positions are changed now. **
Can any one let me know which part I did wrong?

Comment: By default the `levels` of your factor variable are arranged alphabetically. `TRUE, Unknown` gets reordered to `Unknown, Yes` when you change the values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained by @Seth in the comments, the issue is that by changing the label for the `"TRUE"` category to `"Yes"` you change the order of the slices of your pie which is determined by the order of the variable mapped on `fill` aka `work_from_home`. If not explicitly set `character`s or `factor`s are ordered alphabetically.

However, as you computed the positions for your labels manually `geom_text` can't account for that. While you could of course swap the values of `ypos` to account for that, a less error prone way to achieve your result would be use `y = prop` for the labels too but switch to `position = position_stack(vjust=.5)`. This way the labels are "stacked" in the same order as the bars (aka slices of the pie) where `vjust = .5` will center the labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  count_work_from_home,
  aes(x = "", y = prop, fill = work_from_home)
) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = "white") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = prop),
    color = "white",
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Remote jobs vs.Non-remote jobs")
```

[image]

And if you want a different order then convert `work_from_home` to a `factor` and set the order of the levels explicitly:

```
count_work_from_home$work_from_home <- factor(
  count_work_from_home$work_from_home,
  levels = c("Yes", "Unknown")
)

ggplot(
  count_work_from_home,
  aes(
    x = "", y = prop,
    fill = work_from_home
  )
) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = "white") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = prop),
    color = "white",
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Remote jobs vs.Non-remote jobs")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
count_work_from_home <- structure(
  list(
    work_from_home = c("Unknown", "Yes"),
    n = c(13437L, 11009L),
    prop = c(55L, 45L),
    ypos = c(27.5, 77.5)
  ),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2")
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation makes perfect sense.